# Proxmox host and VM running on it see different machines on their network using the same connection

Tags: networking, vlan, aruba

I have run into a weird issue when setting up a new Proxmox host with a VM on it which I wanted to connect to our dedicated storage network running on a separated switch.

The setup is the following:

- all machines connected to the switch share the 192.168.0.0/24 network
- the Proxmox host is connected with 10GB fibre to two ports on the switch
- several other physical machines and VMs on other Proxmox hosts are also connected to the switch (the physical ones via fibre to the switch ports and the VMs via virtual bridges on the other Proxmox hosts, the Proxmox hosts themselves being physical machines connected via fibre)
- the two 10GB NICs on the Proxmox host are set up as a bond in Proxmox with MTU 9000 which is then used as the interface to vmbr1 (which also has MTU set to 9000)
- vmbr1 is passed to the VM as interface1 (interface0 being the normal Proxmox management network running at 1GB on another switch)
- the Proxmox host has IP 192.168.0.122 assigned on vmbr1
- all NICs, bonds and bridges on the Proxmox host are set to "VLAN aware = no"
- the VM running on the Proxmox host sees vmbr1 as an interface named ens19
- the VM has IP 192.168.0.123 assigned via /etc/network/interfaces to ens19 and MTU set to 9000
- running "ip a" on the VM shows that the IP .123 is assigned and MTU 9000 is set
- running "ip a" on the Proxmox host shows that the .122 IP is assigned and MTU 9000 is set
- there are 14 other machines/VM in this network: .3/10/11/14/20/31/35/41/42/101/102/231/232/254 (.10 is a storage server with NFS shares and .254 is the switch)

Now on to the weird part: The VM and the Proxmox host have (partial) access each to a different set of these 14 other machines.

The symptoms are these:

- when I run "showmount -e 192.168.0.10" to list available shares from the storage server, this command shows the shares when run inside the VM but times out when run on the Proxmox host
- when I run "nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24" on the VM, it finds these hosts up: .10/11/20/31/41/102/122/123
- when I run the same nmap command on the Proxmox host, it finds these hosts up: .3/14/35/42/101/122/123/231/232/254

Two completely different sets out of the 16 hosts (including the PM host and the VM) on the network! Only the PM host and VM themselves are found in both sets.

Now when I try to ping the hosts shown in nmap, only some of them respond to the ping. This is true on the PM host as well as on the VM. There is no firewall (iptables) configured on any of the machines/VMs.

All other physical machines and VMs on this network (except for the PM host and VM in question here) are able to ping each other freely and there is always a response.

At first I thought this was some weird VLAN setting on the physical ports of the switch but then why would the PM host and VM (which are both obviously connected to the same physical port) discover different hosts?

Side note: On the Proxmox management interface (IP range 10.0.10.0/24) nmap discovers all hosts that are on that network. Both on the PM host and on the VM. There are no issues with ping on this network, either.

Anyone with any suggestions what is happening here? I'm a little at a loss.

---

EDIT 2024-03-21:

After checking the switch (Aruba 3810M) there is the following config on it:

- the switch has 16 SPF+ ports
- it has 2 VLANs: "DEFAULT" (1) and "STORAGE" (2) under "Switch Configuration -> VLAN -> VLAN Names"
- primary VLAN is set to "DEFAULT" under "Switch Configuration -> VLAN -> VLAN Support"
- all 16 ports are assigned to the "STORAGE" VLAN as "untagged" under "Switch Configuration -> VLAN -> VLAN Port Assignment" (for "DEFAULT" VLAN they all show "No")
- the "DEFAULT" VLAN has IP range 10.0.10.0/24 and "STORAGE" has 192.168.0.0/24 under "Switch Configuration -> Internet (IP) Service"
- all 16 ports show as "enabled", "mode -> auto" and "Flow Ctrl -> Disable" under "Switch Configuration -> Port/Trunk Settings"

So far, so normal, I think?

Now, two things on the switch could have something to do with the problem (as far as I assume with limited networking knowledge):

1. under "Switch Configuration -> System Information" it shows "Jumbo Max Frame Size" as 9216 and "Jumbo IP MTU" as 9198

In Proxmox and on all the hosts, MTU is set to 9000 for the interfaces going into this switch, is this problematic that it is not exactly 9198?

2. under "Switch Configuration -> Port/Trunk Settings" it shows that ports 1-8 are assigned to "Groups" and their "Type" is "LACP", while ports 9-16 show nothing under "Group" and "Type"

As far as I understand, LACP aggregates multiple ports so that they can transmit with their combined bandwidth (?).

This would make sense in this case, because two ports are in each group here and these two each go to one server:

- ports 1 + 2 are in Group "Trk1" and go to physical server with IP ending in .10
- ports 3 + 4 are in Group "Trk2" and go to physical server with IP ending in .20
- ports 5 + 6 are in Group "Trk3" and go to physical server with IP ending in .11
- ports 7 + 8 are in Group "Trk4" and go to physical server with IP ending in .12 (this is the Proxmox host in question here)

The other ports (which are not in groups) go to the following servers:

- ports 9 + 10 go to physical server with IP ending in .232
- port 11 goes to physical server with IP ending in .101
- port 12 goes to physical server with IP ending in .102
- ports 13 + 14 go to physical server with IP ending in .231 (this server is another PVE host which hosts the VMs with IPs .3/14/31/35/41/42)
- ports 15 + 16 have no cable attached

Now, none of this information helps me with the problem, it only makes it stranger.

As seen in the `nmap` scan above, the problematic PVE host (.12) and its VM (.122) both detect **different** VMs running on the **same** other PVE host (.231) using the same ports on the switch (13 + 14).

So now their view of the network differs even though the senders of the pings/nmap-scans (.12 and .122) are on the same physical ports (7 + 8) **AND** the receivers (for example: VMs .41 [detected only by .122] and .42 [detected only by .12]) are also on the same host (.231) which uses physical ports (13 + 14).

I thought this would likely be a VLAN issue, but after checking the switch, this seems not to be the case. I have no idea why the PVE host and its VM have different views of the network. Is there any other place (except VLAN and physical ports) where traffic could be separated? There is no firewall in this network.

Comment: So well, "investigate". See ARP tables on all sides — does it resolve MAC addresses? See bridge FDBs on hosts — does it see the right MACs in the right place? When you find some discrepancy (e.g. some MAC doesn't resolve), capture traffic (tcpdump is your friend) and observe which packets go or don't go where.

Comment: This was as far as my network knowledge allowed me to investigate. That's why I'm asking for help here. The MAC addresses that nmap shows are exactly the ones that "ip a" shows on the respective servers, it just doesn't detect all of them. Running "ip neighbor show" will show any IP I tried to ping (if it was also discovered by nmap) once as "STALE" until I ping it again. Then it will change to "REACHABLE" regardless whether the ping had a response or timed out.

Comment: Ok, this was important thing. It seems, ARP if working. So capture on various places (in the host: on the physical NIC, on TAP NIC) while pinging, to find out where it fails. N.B.: what about PVE firewall? Could it interfere?

Comment: I will check the capture today and also check on the switch itself (it has not outside connection, only directly with cable to console port). The firewall setting in PVE is set like this: Datacenter level -> off, Node level -> on (but no rules set), VM level -> off. I think I heard that if Datacenter level is off, all sub-levels will not have FW even if they're set to "on" (?). The settings on node level are: SMURFS filter on, TCP flags filter off, NDP on, nf_conntrack_max and _timeout_established -> Default

Comment: I checked on our other Proxmox hosts and the FW settings described above seem to be the default when installing fresh Proxmox: DC -> off, Node -> on, VM -> off with SMURFS and NDP -> on in Node level. They are set like this when I install a fresh Proxmox to a blank machine and create one VM.

Comment: I also now tried `nmap` without any options (so, no -sn) and it finished in 10s on the Proxmox host but is still running (>4 minutes now) on the VM. On the Proxmox hosts, it correctly detected open ports on those servers that it found. /// Correction: I cancelled `nmap` on the VM and tried running it again a minute later and then it finished in 8 seconds and showed the correct open ports on all hosts that it found. So there seems to be intermittent problems maybe.

Comment: Okay, this is new:

I monitored the incoming packets with `bmon` on one of the servers that don't respond to ping while pinging it from the VM/PVE host and monitored the outgoing packets from the VM/PVE host as well.


The RX packet counter on the pinged host increases with every TX packet from the VM/PVE host. So does the TX packet counter on the pinged host. Still, ping says "Destination Host Unreachable" on both, the VM and the PVE host. So, the pinged hosts are actually receiving and responding to the ping, but the VM/PVE host are not getting the response!

Comment: I also now checked the ARP tables! Both, the VM and the PVE host show "(incomplete)" for all servers that they didn't detect with `nmap` and the correct MAC for the ones they did detect. Strangely, one of the servers (192.168.0.20) shows up with the correct MAC address in BOTH ARP tables, even though it is only detected by `nmap` from the VM and says "Destination Host Unreachable" when pinging from BOTH (VM and PVE)... the APR table of this sever (192.168.0.20) has both correct MAC addresses of the VM and the PVE host.

Comment: I have now checked the switch and added the information to the original thread above. TL/DR: No VLANs there. Still no idea why PVE host and its VM see different parts of the network...

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Your very first answer was basically the solution, not technically but strategically: INVESTIGATE! I did today and that lead me to the solution after a few hours! :-)

Comment: Post your answer as an answer, don't edit it into your question!

Comment: I put it into the question because in these comments there is no formatting (or am I using it wrong?) and this way, people who come to the thread with the same problem will see the answer immediately.

Comment: You are using it wrong. Don't put it into comments or question, put it into the *answer* box below your question. Answers have the same formatting capabilities as questions.

Comment: Ohhh, there is an "Answer your own question" button even below the comments! I didn't even see that before. Put the solution there now and removed it from the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

LOL, I found the answer...

as noted in the switch config, the two ports where the problematic PVE host was connected were set to LACP mode on the switch while the bond I created on the PVE host was set to "active-backup"!

This for some reason split the network among the PVE host and its VM!

If anybody can explain, why this misconfiguration leads to this split, I would be happy to know! :-)

Setting the bond on the PVE host to LACP as well and rebooting the host, everything works now!